# How do I break a label up vertically in TIKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When working with tikz, I've encountered this issue that I can't get the axis labels to take up multiple lines. In some cases, the text on the axis is quite long, and so it becomes not very legible. In the example below, it would be better if the label

> AAAAAAAAAAAA

was broken (i.e. extended vertically):

> AAAAAA-

> AAAAAA

How do you suggest I implement this change?

I have tried entering in AAAA//AAAA manually, but does not seem to be recognised by tikz.

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\centering
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y    
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA   0.09
B   0.06 
C   0.04
D   0.02
}{\mytablee}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    ymin=0,
    symbolic x coords={AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,B,C,D},
    xtick=data
]
\addplot
  plot [mark=none, black, dashed]
  table {\mytablee};
\end{axis} 
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {Test};
\node[below,font=\large] at (current bounding box.south) {Sample};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `x tick label style={text width=1.7cm,align=center}`, your `xtick label`s will wrap. You need the `\\` in the label to indicate the break point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y
AAAAAAA\\AAAAAAA   0.09
B   0.06
C   0.04
D   0.02
}{\mytablee}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    x tick label style={text width=1.7cm,align=center}, % <-- added
    ymin=0,
    symbolic x coords={AAAAAAA\\AAAAAAA,B,C,D},
    xtick=data
]
\addplot
  plot [mark=none, black, dashed]
  table {\mytablee};
\end{axis}
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {Test};
\node[below,font=\large] at (current bounding box.south) {Sample};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```